# how to plot or render all values of x axis (years in this case)

Tags: r, shiny

code that I am using to create a graph.

```
arimamodel<-ts(dt$Record,start = c(2009,1),frequency = 12)
arimamodel

fit_Amodel<-auto.arima(arimamodel,seasonal=TRUE)
fit_Amodel

predict(fit_Amodel)

autoplot(forecast(fit_Amodel,h=24)) +
ggtitle("Delivery Records Year-Wise") +
xlab("(Delivery Year)") + ylab("(Delivery Records)") +
theme_bw() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

I have also tried ...

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 2009,to=2020, by =2 ))
```

would someone please tell me how to plot it desired way.

it's throwing an error: 'origin' must be supplied'

Comment: try the `scales` package and `scale_x_date`

Comment: scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year") method is plotting the values of year-mth-date and I just want the year to be printed and is there any method for the values of y-axis as well

Comment: `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", labels = "%Y")`